# How does YouTube respond to Quota increase requests?

Tags: youtube-api

my application constantly runs out of quota (queries-per-day). We are at the max 60K queries per day.
I have filled out the form requesting quota increase (YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form) twice already in the last couple of months, but YouTube does not respond.
In this form, one has to give YouTube an account and pw for them to login to the tool I have done that and I can see that they've logged on the tool multiple times, but they don't answer!!!

1) Is there any way to contact YouTube about this issue?

2) Has anyone requested quota increase and got it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) We have tried, never came close to a human being.

2) We have multiple times (n) for 2 different projects on 1 client (account).

1 * 2 * n requests in the duration of 14 months.

The result was the following:

While waiting, the 1. project got reduced quota two times:

1. 1.Project from 600 000 to 250 000 quotas.
2. 1.Project from 250 000 to 80 000 quotas.

The 1. project 1.time quota increase request has been submitted 14 months ago.
The 2. project 1.time quota increase request has been submitted 8 months ago.

After a total of 14 months of waiting the 2.project got approved quota increase without any notification or feedback.

The waiting time for the 2. project was around 5-6 months until the approval issue came via email. After fixing the approval issue we waited around 2-3 months and got the final quota increase from 10 000 to 500 000.

I have also read several SO answers and other forum posts.

In short:

It is madness, and it is not Sparta. It is pure incompetence.